# Finding a contour integral of product of analytic functions in a region

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$ and that the series converges when $|z|<2$. By integrating $f(z)g(z^{-1})z^{-1}$ around the unit circle, show that

$$\sum_{n=0}^n a_n b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{i\theta})g(e^{-i\theta})d\theta.$$

I'm not sure where to go from my working:
Define $h(z) = f(z)g(z^{-1})z^{-1}$. 
Let $\Gamma$ be the unit circle contour.
$\Gamma(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.
Then
$$\int_{\Gamma}f(z)g(z^{-1})z^{-1}dz = i\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})g(e^{-i\theta})d\theta.$$

I know it's not much but I'm not sure how to advance from here. At first, I thought that we could use the Residue theorem however, I can't think of a way of finding the residue of $h$ at $z=0$, since $f$ is a taylor series, $g(\frac{1}{z})$ is a laurent series with only negative powers...

Comment: Try calculating the integral . Use the series expansions of $f,g$ inside the integral and then use the multiplication of the series . Find the terms one by one and then use cauchy integral formula and you will have the result.